# Android app that continuously displays lyrics of whatever song can be heard in the room (like Shazam but continuous)

Tags: gratis, android, music-recognition, lyrics

I am usually in places where music is playing in the background, and I often want to see what the singer just said, because I failed to hear a particular word or to make sure I understood a word correctly.

So, I need a gratis Android app that constantly listens in the background and displays lyrics scrolling on the screen.

Example of how the screen could look like, automatically transitioning from the song "Chandelier" to the song "White privilege":

```
Oh, I'm just holding on for tonight,
On for tonight, on for tonight.

--- White Privilege, by Macklemore ---
Now nod your head and wake up,
I see so many people lost who really try to pretend,
```

As you can see, both songs are shown on the same screen, and I don't have to touch anything. The next song is shown as soon as it is successfully recognized.

Shazam does not fit because as far as I know:

- You have to manually push a button every time a new song starts
- Lyrics are not shown continuously: at the end of a song the lyrics just stop scrolling, the lyrics of the next song don't get loaded.

Other features:

- The name of the song and artist of the current song should be visible at all times.
- The few next and previous lyrics lines should be shown, and be scrollable (at least two lines in each direction: n-2 n-1 **n** n+1 n+2).

Comment: I don't use any, but may I (as usual with Android App requests) point to [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_identification) while waiting for answers? And happy Halloween while doing so, especially when counting the trackers used by those apps … (well, you didn't put "no trackers" as requirement :D)

Comment: Do you want to be able to scroll backwards? If so, how many songs/lines of lyrics should the app remember?